# "Shadow" showing on vertices of model

Tags: modeling, mesh

There's a shadow showing in vertices, how can I make this disappear?

Seems like something is wrong with the model.

[image]

Comment: "*Seems like something is wrong with the model.*" Your topology. There is a huge ngon, Blender can't fill it properly.

Comment: i dont understand why..
blender fill properly when all the vertices was with 0 on Z cordinates.. but after when i chance the Z cordinates of some vertices this happen..
Sorry, im beginner

Comment: Ngons only work when vertices on the same plane. If the vertices is not in a plane, it will be very difficult to determined your face by simple algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to display n-gons they need to be triangulated because video cards draw triangles only to simplify calculations. When the n-gon is automatically triangulated it so happens that there is an edge where you see the 'shadow' that's why it is visible there and that is why your solution works - it includes triangulation without any edges going from one side to another.

Comment: Now i get it, thanks man

Answer (score 0):

hey guy i use ALT + F to fill and works better
[image]